# Get most searched terms from indexes that are referenced by an alias

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana, alias, ranking

The search is pointing to an alias.
The indexing process create a new index every 5 minutes.
Then the alias is updated, pointing to the new index.
The index is recreated to avoid sync problems that can occur if we update item by item when a change is made.

However, I need to keep track of the searched terms to produce a dashboard to list the most searched terms in a period. Or even using Kibana to show/extract it.

*The searched terms can be multi words, such as "white", "white summer night", etc. We are looking to rank the term, not the individual words.

I don't have experience with Elasticsearch and the searches that I have tried did not bring relevant solutions.

Thanks for the help!

```
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "catalog*",       "alias" : "catalog-index" } },
        { "add"    : { "index" : "catalog1234566", "alias" : "catalog-index" } }
    ]
}
```

Mappings:

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "created_at":{
            "type":"integer"
         },
         "search_terms_key":{
            "type":"keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "match_all":{
         
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "search_terms_key":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"search_terms_key",
            "value_type":"string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log the search terms (or entire queries, if necessary), ingest those into Elasticsearch, then analyze them with Kibana. The index alias configuration is not relevant.

You should get the logs either directly from whatever connects to Elasticsearch, or from a proxy between it and Elasticsearch.

You *could* get Elasticsearch itself to log queries, but that's usually a bad idea in terms of performance.

Since it's the entire term you're after, be sure to use `keyword` mapping on the search term.

Once you have search terms ingested, use a `terms` aggregation to show the most popular searches.

[edit: make explicit that search terms need to be logged, not full DSL queries]

Comment: Hi tomr, thanks for your reply. I have done it, using the field as keyword and using an aggregation to summarise it daily. It is not logging the query, just inserting the search_term in a different index, then at the end of the day it is extracted from the index using the the terms aggregation and inserting the result in a table.

Comment: Good point - I have updated my answer to be clearer that it's the *search terms* that need to be logged and ingested. If the answer was helpful, please upvote or accept as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)